# jsonschema: optional elements from limited collection

Tags: jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Minimal example (python 3.x):

```
_required_fields = {
    "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 1,
    },
    "name: {
       "type": "string" 
   }
}

_optional_fields = {
    "address": {
       "type": "string" 
   }
}

my_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        **_required_fields ,
        **_optional_fields
    },
    "required": [key for key in _required_fields ],
    # "additionalProperties": ???
}
```

The schema should make sure that all required fields are in the JSON (that works fine). And it should limit the additional properties to those in the `_optional_fields` dict. (where I'm stuck).

If there are no optional properties, you simply set `additionalProperties` to `False`. Then there's the `minProperties` and `maxProperties` to limit the number of additional properties. But how to limit these to a fixed selection?

*EDIT:*

Thanks to @Relequestual. The solution was pretty straightforward. I set `"additionalProperties": False` and now it accepts only the required and optional fields and nothing outside these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`additionalProperties` to `false` prevents any properties not already defined in `properties`.

It's not related to and does not interact with `required` or `min/maxProperties`